# Oracle SQL MERGE 2 SELECT STATEMENTS while updating

Tags: sql, oracle, select, merge

I need to update a table by refering to column value from another SELECT and some constants that column has.
I want to update TABLEA checkA and checkB columns when checkA is NULL AND ID matches with that of TABLEB column ID and also update when TABLEA ID = 3

The above SQL is not returning me rows from TABLEA where ID is 1 and 3

```
TABLEA

ID NAME    STATE   checkA   checkA
1   John    VA      null     null
2   SEAN    MD      null     null
3   CARL    SD      null     null


TABLEB
ID   ROLL_ID
1     01



UPDATE TABLEA tb  SET checkA = 'modified' ,checkA = 'modified'  where checkA is NULL AND
ID in 
(select DISTINCT ab.ID fRom  TABLEB ab where ab.ROLL_ID IN 
( 01 ) )

UNION

 select DISTINCT ID from TABLEA tbl WHERE ID in (3) AND  where checkA is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fix syntax (and other) errors, update works.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from tablea;

        ID NAME ST CHECKA
---------- ---- -- ---------------
         1 John VA
         2 Sean MD
         3 Carl SD

SQL> select * from tableb;

        ID RO
---------- --
         1 01
```

Update, fixed:

```
SQL> update tablea tb
  2    set checka = 'modified'
  3  where checka is null
  4    and id in
  5      (select distinct ab.id
  6         from  tableb ab
  7         where ab.roll_id in ( '01' )
  8       union
  9       select distinct id
 10         from tablea tbl
 11         where id in (3)
 12           and checka is null
 13      );

2 rows updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from tablea;

        ID NAME ST CHECKA
---------- ---- -- ---------------
         1 John VA modified
         2 Sean MD
         3 Carl SD modified

SQL>
```

Note that table can't have two columns with the same name (which is what your sample data and code suggests).

Comment: `union ...` part may be adjusted as long as updated table is the same as `union`ed one and the filter is applied to the same column. Thus, it becomes `and id in (select ... from tableb ab where ... union select 3 from dual)`